# What situation may cause Chrome to delay rendering?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-rendering

Currently working on an web application, I encountered Chrome to delay the rendering of pages for a long time or indefinetely.

This happens to very small page sources, eg. a simple, but correct HTML skeleton with only one short paragraph of text.

Chrome loads these pages, the mouse pointer returns to idle state, and the developer tools network monitor confirms the complete transfer. The tab however stays empty white. The rendering can be provoked by toggling tabs then, or marking the content for example, after which the page appears completely.

I wonder if this is caused by a non-conform too simple HTML, or something more elaborate, depending on my response headers, the type of connection (maybe using keepalive).

Any ideas or similiar observations?

Comment: i've observed the same. my remedy was to perform a "hard refresh" `ctrl` + `f5`. this not only occurred on apps that i'm developing, but randomly with other sites.

Comment: so this is clearly a bug of Chrome, but the reason for it, mostly a useful performance feature gone wrong I guess, would be interesting to know, to prevent it happening on your own service...

Comment: Some progress: I found the same effects as describe in bug code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321286 . The behavour matches exactly, however the solution doesn not. If the solution would work, I would stamp this just a rarely occuring Chrome bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on other browsers, if it works fine then the problem resides in chrome. try to clear browser data, re-install chrome, or update.

If the issue also appear on other browsers then you have to check your code, internet connection, or check your PC for viruses that might slow down your browser.

Comment: The problem definitely resides in Chrome, but as other people encountered it too, and myself only encountered on my website under construction, I need to solve it by the means of my website, otherwise other users may later encounter the same problems.

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing the same issue, and found this discussion.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Following workaround works for me:

```
 body
{
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
-webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix{
from{   opacity: 1; }
to{ opacity: 1; }
}
```

Hope this helps you out as well!

Comment: This seems discussing external font related problems, as the page mentioned linked some and the complaint was about text not rendering. However, I encounter a total blank page with nothing rendering.